# Show if an SQL Row is empty

Tags: php, if-statement

I've got an SQL Statement setup and a repeating region, Now with the repeating region I have an Dynamic Image. If the Database Table in question is empty, I would like to not show an image at all, or maybe replace it with a blank image. What I'd like to know is how do I do this?

My code is :

```
mysql_select_db($database_db_connect, $db_connect);
$query_homepage_ticked = "SELECT * FROM disp_ticked";
$homepage_ticked = mysql_query($query_homepage_ticked, $db_connect) or die(mysql_error());
$row_homepage_ticked = mysql_fetch_assoc($homepage_ticked);
$totalRows_homepage_ticked = mysql_num_rows($homepage_ticked);

<?php do { ?>
      <li>
        <a href="property.php?category_id=<?php echo $row_homepage_ticked['category_id']; ?>&property_id=<?php echo $row_homepage_ticked['property_id']; ?>&image_id=<?php echo $row_homepage_ticked['image_id']; ?>">
          <img src="carousel.php?image=propertyimages/<?php echo $row_homepage_ticked['image_url']; ?>" width="175px" height="130px" />
        </a>
      </li>
      <?php } while ($row_homepage_ticked = mysql_fetch_assoc($homepage_ticked)); ?>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you heared about if statment?

Comment: Thats what I'm trying to do, but unsure how to structure it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php 
if(isset($row_homepage_ticked['image_url']) 
     && !empty($row_homepage_ticked['image_url']) 
{ 
    ?>
    <img src="carousel.php?image=propertyimages/<?php echo $row_homepage_ticked['image_url']; ?>" width="175px" height="130px" />      
    <?php 
} 
?>
```

Comment: @Col : If table is empty, then don't you need to check that column name is set or not?

Comment: @Col : StuBlackett is using do while loop, so table is empty mysql_fetch_assoc will return false. Then it will give undefinded array key index error/ warning.

Comment: @cOL : Please respond to my answer.

Comment: 1. using do..while loop here has no sense. 2. row should be checked for emptiness earlier, before outputting a href code which will be erroneous too. As many other lamers here, you wrote the code, unusable in the real life. It makes me sick. None of you trying to think then writing an answer. 3. using isset with !empty is a nonsense anyway. Statisfied?

Comment: Thanks for that Col. A neater way to do it and your arguement makes sense.

Comment: @Col : thanks Col. but I just thought to solve his issue. I didn't notice that. By the way, thanks again.

Comment: `I just thought to solve his issue` - that's what I am talking about. why not to look a bit further, wider?

Answer (score 0):

Try this and see...

<?php if $row_homepage_ticked['image_url']="" ?>
  <img src="path_of_the_default_image" width="175px" height="130px" />

<?php else ?>
  <img src="carousel.php?image=propertyimages/<?php echo $row_homepage_ticked['image_url']; ?>" width="175px" height="130px" />

Answer (score -1):

```
foreach($row_homepage_ticked as $value)
{
if($value['image_url'] == "")
{
// then show blank image
}
else
{
//your normal code
}
}
```